# How to read -argument from within a .sh shell script

Tags: bash, sh

I'm calling a bash script with the following arguments:

```
myscript.sh -d /tmp -e dev -id 12345 -payload /tmp/test.payload
```

and inside the script, would like to get the value for the -payload. I don't really care about the other arguments, but they will be present in the call.

Here's some code that almost works on retrieving the argument:

```
while getopts "d:e:payload:id:" arg; do
  case $arg in
    payload)
        echo "payload"
        ;;
  esac
done
```

Of course **payload)** in the case control structure doesn't work, so how can I grab the value for -payload and assign it to a variable?

Comment: `getopts` (a program, as opposed to the `getopt` command) supports long flags (`--foo`), though I think not on OSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i not sure if this is the best way to handle it... but check [these marked lines in a script](https://github.com/artmees/rm/blob/master/rm.sh#L53-L85)

in your case i'd use

```
while test $# -gt 0; do
  case "$1" in
    -payload)
      shift
      PAYLOAD=$1
      ;;
     *)
     # Catch other parameters here
     # this part is not relevant 
     # to the answer but I added it
     # to avoid infinite loop mentioned
     shift
     ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add a shift after esac? Otherwise you get an infinite loop as unmatched parameters aren't consumed.

Comment: I edited the answer... I only added the relavent part that answer the question... Thanks for mentioning this @Martin